# Qt QFileSystemWatcher: signal fileChanged() gets emited only once

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying the `QFileSystemWatcher` out and it somehow doesn't work as expected. Or am I doing something wrong?

I've set the `QFileSystemWatcher` to watch a single file. When I modify the file for the first time, `fileChanged()` gets emited, that's OK. But when I modify the file again, `fileChanged()` doesn't get emited anymore.

Here is the source code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow window;

  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:

  MainWindow();

private slots:

  void directoryChanged(const QString & path);
  void fileChanged(const QString & path);

private:

  QFileSystemWatcher * watcher;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
  connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(fileChanged(const QString &)));
  connect(watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(directoryChanged(const QString &)));
  watcher->addPath("path to directory");
  watcher->addPath("path to file");
}

void MainWindow::directoryChanged(const QString & path)
{
  qDebug() << path;
}

void MainWindow::fileChanged(const QString & path)
{
  qDebug() << path;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

**Edit 1**

I ran this code under Linux.

**Edit 2**

I actually need to check all MetaPost files in a tree given by some directory, whether they were modified. I will probably stick to my alternative solution, which is to run QTimer every second and manually check all files. The QFileSystemWatcher probably does this in similar fashion internally, but probably more effectively.

Comment: `QFileSystemWatcher` is a platform dependent wrapper class for native file/directory monitoring API, so knowing the platform is important.

Comment: The platform is Linux.

Comment: I am a bit surprised. I had to write code under Linux to handle the effect that when I wrote large files (serveral 100mb), the signal fired several times. Did you move or renamed your file?

Comment: I've written to my file in a text editor, then I saved the changes. For the first time, the signal got emited, but never again.

Comment: Signal `directoryChanged()` is emited always. This is really wierd... I don't understand why is it so. It wouldn't be a problem, if I was able to get the name of the changed file from the signal `directoryChanged()`, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @pizet, pure guesswork, but since watching stops, when a file is deleted or renamed, could it be that your text editor deletes the file and recreates it when it saves it? And yes, I know this sounds crazy. :-) But should be easy to test: 'ls -i <your file>'. Check the inode number before and after saving.

Comment: Well, this would probably explain everything, but I don't know. I'm using Vim. When call `watcher->files()`, I always get the watched path, so the file is probably always watched... I don't know. Maybe the problem is, that I do something silly here and I don't know about it. But when I use another editor it behaves in the same fashion.

Comment: @Greenflow, you were right. Wow, so this QFileSystemWatcher is completely useless for me then. That's a real pity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Had the same problem just now. Seems like QFileSystemWatcher thinks that the file is deleted even if it's only modified. Well at least on Linux file system. My simple solution was:

```
if (QFile::exists(path)) {
    watcher->addPath(path);
}
```

Add the above to your handler of `fileChanged()`. Change the word `watcher` as necessary.

Comment: addPath often yields “file not exists” warning, how should I handle it in the handler function, should I wait for a few time before call addpath

Comment: @user3450805 My original answer was:
if (QFile::exists(path)) {
    watcher->addPath(path);
}
but Mats thought he really really had to edit it...

Comment: @Peter, I reverted to your original version, as the test is not redundant. For example, the file may have been deleted, which results in a warning as mentioned by user3450805.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem using Qt5 on Linux. Found out the reason :

Some text editors, like kate, don't modify the contents of a file, but replace the original file with a new file. Replacing a file will delete the old one (`IN_DELETE_SELF` event), so qt will stop watching the file.

A solution is to also watch the file's directory for creation events.

Comment: Thanks for explaining rather than just spitting the solution. =)

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm your problem with current Qt5 and Linux.
In addition to the answer given by Peter I solved this problem by adding the following code to the end of the slot-function:

```
QFileInfo checkFile(path);
while(!checkFile.exists())
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
watcher->addPath(path);
```

Note that if you add the path immediately, the file often does not exist yet, you get a warning and nothing will be added at all and the watcher looses this path. Therefore, you have to wait/sleep until the file is back to life again, then add it.

Also note that in this example I used C++11 and included  and  for realizing the sleep.

Comment: I went with this solution though it occurs to me that this could end up in an infinite loop if the file is never created (actually the file may have been deleted outright). In my use-case I expect the file to always exist (just being updated from another process) so this works for me.